# Не могу переместить index.html, webpack

Tags: webpack

Пытаюсь настроить конфигурацию webpack4. Но не не могу переместить index.html в другую папку.

Нормально работает только если index.html и webpack.config.js находятся в одной папке.

В противном случае получаю Cannot GET / и ошибка "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```